# How can I cout the content of the vector?

Tags: c++

I'm resolving a competitive problem and I need to make sure that the user's input passes correctly throw the vector. How can I print the values of the vector?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
int result;


while(cin >> a >> b >> c){

    result = 0;

}
vector <int > v;
while(cin >> d);{
    v.push_back(d);

    }
    for( int i = 0; i < v.size();i++);
        cout << v[i] << endl;
    if (a>=b) cout << 0 << endl;

    else {

    }           
}
```

Comment: Think about your semicolons... Should you have it after e.g. `while (...)`? How about after `for (...)`? Do some [debugging of your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (especially step through the code in a debugger).

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and never use `using namespace std`

Comment: You should format your code before you post it here. You can use http://format.krzaq.cc/. Then you probably would see the problems with the semicolons.

Comment: If you would look at your compiler's warnings, you could get a very helpful message: `main.cpp:21:16: warning: while loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
while(cin >> d);{
               ^
main.cpp:21:16: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
1 warning and 1 error generated.`

Comment: `);` marks a loop that is very sad because it would like to do something but it is not doing anything

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in your code

In

> ```
> while(cin >> a >> b >> c){
>
>    result = 0;
>
>  }
> ```

is probably not what you want because you will exit the loop only on EOF or is one oe the input is not an *int*

considering the code after you do not want to close the *while* just after `result = 0;`, so the '}' must be removed

In

> ```
>  while(cin >> d);{
> ```

you certainly do not want to have an empty body for the loop, the ';' must be removed

In

> ```
>  for( int i = 0; i < v.size();i++);
> ```

you certainly do not want to have an empty body for the loop, the ';' must be removed at the end of the line, that also allow *i* to be valid in the next line `cout << v[i] << endl;` else you cannot compile

Note you mix signed/unsigned, better to use a `size_t` rather than an *int* for *i*

Note `while(cin >> d)` stops on EOF or if an invalid *int* is enter, but in that case you go back on the first *while* whose cannot runs because of EOF or the error. If you want to loop again out of the EOF case you have to clear the error and bypass the invalid input, else you do not want to loop so replace the first *while* by an *if*

You set *result* and *c* but you never use them.

---

A proposal with the two loops:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int d;
  int result;

  while(cin >> a >> b >> c) {
    result = 0;

    vector <int > v;

    while(cin >> d) {
      v.push_back(d);
    }

    for( size_t i = 0; i < v.size();i++)
      cout << v[i] << endl;

    if (a>=b)
      cout << 0 << endl;
    else {

    }

    // clear error
    cin.clear();

    string dummy;

    getline(cin, dummy); // or use cin.ignore(...);
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
vxl15036 /tmp % g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.cc
vxl15036 /tmp % ./a.out
1 2 3
11 22 33 44 55 a
11
22
33
44
55
1 2 3
111 222 a
111
222
b
vxl15036 /tmp %
```

I use the invalid integer *a* to stop the second *while* then the invalid integer *b* to stop the first *while* after two turns

Answer (score 0):

Your program will work better without the erroneous semi-colons.

```
while(cin >> d);{
               ^ HERE
```

and

```
for( int i = 0; i < v.size();i++);
                                 ^ HERE
```

A semi-colon ends a statement, so writing

```
for( int i = 0; i < v.size();i++);
```

is exactly the same as writing

```
for( int i = 0; i < v.size();i++)
{
}
```

So this code

```
for( int i = 0; i < v.size();i++);
cout << v[i];
```

should not compile because the `i` variable is only declared inside the for loop, but because of the extra semi-colon `v[i]` is after the for loop not inside it.